# Can you add values to an Oracle APEX Shuttle item using a textbox?

Tags: textbox, oracle-apex

The LHS is still dynamically populated with a query, but if it doesn't have a value that you want, then you can just type in a value in the textbox and then add that to the RHS of the shuttle (and update the corresponding tables in the database when you submit). It should also be okay to add that to the LHS when you click on the '<' or '<<' button.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is doable. To add the value in the text box to the r.h.s. of the shuttle just do this:

```
:p1_shuttle := :p1_shuttle || ':' || :p1_textitem;
```

(You may need to set the shuttle item's LOV "Display Extra Values" property to "Yes" to be able to see the value.)

You are then able to shuttle the new value to the l.h.s.  However, it won't appear on the l.h.s. after a page refresh unless in the meanwhile your code has added the new value to the table the LOV is based on.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Do I do that in a Computation on the page?